# Copy and paste Bold Text with Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

We are working with selenium to upload ads easy to www.marktplaats.nl and this works well!
Before we used Selenium we uploaded everything by hand. The text part of very advertisement was copied and pasted by hand. The text we copied and pasted had some **bold** parts in it. When it was copied and pasted from a google keep file it worked well. Now we use Selenium and add everything from excel, the **bold** text is gone.

How can you copy and paste easily and consistent with Selenium and still have **bold** text?

Much Thanks for your time and responds!

Answer (score 0):

If the Text box where you are entering the text allows keyboard operation we can do something on the lines of:

1. Select the text enters with the help of Ctrl+A
2. Then press Ctrl+B to make the characters bold

   //enter Text with sendKeys()

   Actions action = new Actions(driver);
   action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("A").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
   action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("B").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();